# How do I code 4 charts (trying to use chart.js) with css grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

Im trying to code 4 charts with chart.js and represent them in a grid (2x2). so i have 4 charts in total and 2 charts next to each other.

Is it possible to implement chart.js in css grid? I have already coded a chart.js with , but it seems not to display if i put it in a grid box.

Does anyone have experience with chart layout, and is there a better/easier way to code charts than with chart.js?

Thank you!!

This is my html with my divs:

```
<div class="chartdivs">
        <!--chart1-->
        <div class="chart1">
            <canvas id="lineCharts" height="160" width="400"></canvas>
        </div>
        <!--chart2-->
        <div class="chart2">
            
        </div>
        <!--chart3-->
        <div class="chart3">
            
        </div>
        <!--chart4-->
        <div class="chart4">
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my css:

```
chartdivs{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "box1 box2"
    "box3 box4";
    
}

.chart1{
    grid-area: box1;
}
.chart2{
    grid-area: box2;
}
.chart3{
    grid-area: box3;
}
.chart4{
    grid-area: box4;
}
```

```
And here is my javascript:

var myChartObject = document.getElementById("lineCharts");



var chart = new Chart(myChartObject, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: ["February", "March", "April", "May","June","July","August","September", "October", "November", "December","January"],
    
        datasets: [{
            label: "Total Covid Cases",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(34, 49, 63, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(34, 49, 63, 1)',
            data: [19,16605,29586,30845,31714,35232,42177,53282,154251,327072,452296,492832],
    
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide at least some of your code so we can help. We are not here to write the code for you.

Comment: sorry about that, i forgot to add my code

Comment: yes, it is possible to implement chart.js in css grid. please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/oxchsum3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just had some typos in your CSS:

```css
/* Here is a dot missing */
chartdivs{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    /* Here is a whitespace too much after "1" */
    grid-template-columns: 1 fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "box1 box2"
    "box3 box4";
    
}
```

See the working example below.

```js
var myChartObject = document.getElementById("lineCharts");

var chart = new Chart(myChartObject, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: ["February", "March", "April", "May","June","July","August","September", "October", "November", "December","January"],
    
        datasets: [{
            label: "Total Covid Cases",
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(34, 49, 63, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(34, 49, 63, 1)',
            data: [19,16605,29586,30845,31714,35232,42177,53282,154251,327072,452296,492832],
    
        }]
    }
});
```

```css
.chartdivs{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "box1 box2"
    "box3 box4";
}

.chart1{
    grid-area: box1;
}
.chart2{
    grid-area: box2;
}
.chart3{
    grid-area: box3;
}
.chart4{
    grid-area: box4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chartdivs">
    <!--chart1-->
    <div class="chart1">
        <canvas id="lineCharts" height="160" width="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <!--chart2-->
    <div class="chart2">

    </div>
    <!--chart3-->
    <div class="chart3">

    </div>
    <!--chart4-->
    <div class="chart4">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now finished all 4 charts, but my css code doesn't put them in a 2x2 grid. I have also corrected the mistakes you have mentioned Josef.

```
 .chartdivs{
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "box1 box2"
    "box3 box4";
    
}



.myFirstChart{
    grid-area: box1;
}
.mySecondChart{
    grid-area: box2;
}
.myThirdChart{
    grid-area: box3;
}
.myFourthChart{
    grid-area: box4;
}
```

my 4 charts are represented below each other. Is there something else I could try?

Comment: That's weird. Would you mind providing a runnable example? It looks like your code is correct by itself ;)